# Intersection of line and circle, conditions for tangency

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find the quadratic equation in $x$ whose roots give the $x$-coordinates of the points where the line $y = mx$ intersects the circle $x^2 + y^2 + 20x + 40y + 450 = 0$.
>
> What is the geometrical relation between the line and the circle if this quadratic equation has coincident roots? Write down the algebraic condition involving $m$ for this to happen and hence find the equations of the tangents from the origin to the circle. Find the coordinates of the points of contact of these tangents.

Sorry, I know this is a lot of questions packed into one but I really can't crack this problem. I think that the quadratic equation the question is initially asking for is this:
$x^2+20x+m^2x^2+40mx=-450$. The answer to the second part (geometrical relation if roots are coincident), I think, is that it is a tangent to the circle as it only has one point of contact. However, for the third and fourth part I can't pull off the coefficients $a$, $b$ and $c$ to substitute into $b^2-4ac$ as I have this $m^2$ and $m$ term.

Comment: There is a double root if and only if the discriminant "$b^2-4ac$", that is, $(20+40m)^2-4(1+m^2)(450)$ is equal to $0$.

Comment: Wow, I just realised that exactly as you said it. Thanks!

Comment: Good! You are welcome.

Comment: Just as a note, usually more descriptive titles are received better. Rather than "math homework help", maybe try describing the problem. Just in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Your answers to the first two parts are fine. The idea for the third part is to think of the expression you have as quadratic in $x$, with $m$ as a constant:
$$ (1+m^2)x^2 + 2(10+20m)x + 450 = 0, $$
and then stick these coefficients into the discriminant:
$$ 4(10+20m)^2-4 \times 450(1+m^2)=0. $$
Now solve that for $m$ (there should be two roots, one for a tangent on both sides of the circle), and then solve the quadratic for the $x$ values. The $y$ values you can easily get from $y=mx$.